# JS animations doesnt work when using pow() or ^ in expressions

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm learning to do some simple animations with JavaScript and canvas and trying to do some simple physics animations, where I do calculations and animate, displacement of the objects.

However, I encountered quite an odd problem when I put :

```
this.ax = (this.vx)^2;
```

Everything works just fine, but when I do :

```
this.ax = (this.vx)^2 + (this.vy)^2;
```

nothing moves. There is work around to just put :

```
this.ax = (this.vx)^2 + this.vy * this.vy;
```

But I wonder why simply squaring or adding Math.pow doesn't do the trick here?

Edit: to try and keep code clean and consistent, I tried using this.vx * this.vx and animations were messed up again.

Comment: The [exponentiation operator is `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) in JavaScript.

Comment: The `^` operator is XOR in JS. Also, where did you use `Math.pow(this.vx, 2)` in your example?

Comment: `^` [Bitwise XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) Are you sure that exactly what you need?